# Increasing req/sec on Nginx CE

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-location

I have a simple location block in nginx conf which echo's back the Server's ip. Its deployed on a 2 core 4gb ram EC2. i am able to get 400 req per second on load testing it.

Made optimizations like logs buffering, opening more FD, followed guidelines in http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2015/11/28/high-load-nginx-config.html.

The peak cpu load on the node is 4-5% and same for memory. I am wondering how can i blow it up even further. Will using Docker help or the cpu load & memory is irrelevant here as it might be running into network congestion. Will increasing EC2 Node size help ?

OS: CentOS. Any help appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: What is preventing the server to take more than 400 req/sec? What does the log say?

Comment: @TanHongTat:  Thats what i am trying to figure out. The Error log is empty. The access log also looks ok. I am using the Kong-Api gateway (build on openresty) but i dont think that should be causing it since the location block is not upstreaming the request.